# How would I set an alert for multiple crosses?

Tags: pine-script

Is this how I would set an alert for multiple crosses keeping them separate but running in one alert?

```
//==ALERTS==
Cond1 = cross(macd1, macd2 ) 
    or  cross(macd3, macd4 ) 
    or  cross(macd9, macd10) 
    or  cross(macd11,macd12) 
    or  cross(macd13,macd14) 
    or  cross(macd15,macd16) 
    or  cross(macd17,macd18) 
    or  cross(macd19,macd20) 
    or  cross(macd21,macd22) 
    or  cross(macd23,macd24) 
    or  cross(macd25,macd26) 
    or  cross(macd27,macd28) 
    or  cross(macd29,macd30)

Cond2 = cross(macd31,macd32) 
    or  cross(macd33,macd34) 
    or  cross(macd35,macd36) 
    or  cross(macd37,macd38) 
    or  cross(macd39,macd40) 
    or  cross(macd41,macd42) 
    or  cross(macd43,macd44) 
    or  cross(macd45,macd46)

alertcondition(Cond1, title="CONSIDER placing a buy", message="CONSIDER placing a buy")
alertcondition(Cond2, title="="close BTC position ",  message="close BTC position ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. If any of your macd crossings occur, the associated alert will fire.